# unable to click a perticular cell in web table in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

the link is "https://www.psacard.com/smrpriceguide/baseball-card-values/1909-11-t206-white-border/1055/".

My question is: How I will get the index of the particular record of which Description contains "Carolina". Also how can I click the hyperlink(Shop) against that row. Please provide solution with python and selenium only.

Comment: This question lacks of prove of effort, you should strongly consider to add the code that you tried and the error, see how to ask questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

With selenium, I usually use xpath searches. I suggest googling xpath, but here's a quick example for your case:

Find a `div` element who's text is exactly `Carolina Brights`:

`//div[text()="Carolina Brights"]`

in selenium:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
browser.implicitly_wait(10)

my_xpath = '//div[text()="Carolina Brights"]]'
my_div = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, my_xpath))
)
my_div.click()
```

Obviously that particular div has no `onClick` so no point clicking it, but you get the idea ...

Comment: Thanks a lot. But how to click on the Shop text in that particular row.

Comment: @debasis Did you read the xpath documentation? If you've found the div with `Carolina Brights`, you need to find it's sibling `<div>`, and then you need that's divs `<a>` child tag, and that's what you click. That search looks kind of, but not quite, like this (read the xpath docs to figure out the error): `//div[text()="Carolina Brights"]/followingsibling:div/a`